# Can you suppress the name change alert from strange weapons?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I find that popup pretty distracting and to be honest, I don't care much that somebody has gotten 100 kills total.

Is there a way to block the message, without completely blocking other messages in the same style (gifts getting given out etc)?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I'm not sure what your talking about as it may just be a server mod

Comment: [Strange weapons](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange#Strange_items) were added in the [Über Update](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/%C3%9Cber_update), they are official. For a demonstration have a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owCQvVl4tXA

Comment: Well, if it's any solace, the allure will die down in a few days, and you'll see less of them. Small comfort, I know.

Comment: An update to TF2 changed it so that the notification is in chat form only. Therefore this question is now unneeded.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable it in Adv. Options by unchecking "Show pop-up alerts while in-game (e.g. trade requests)".

Note: This also disables the notification of trade requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it but it will also disable ***all other*** similar notifications suckh as when some one trades with you.

Answer (score 0):

Valve published a article explaining how to turn off those pop ups in your options.  Then, they were brilliant enough to *not actually implement the option*.

Keep an eye out for it in an upcoming patch.

Comment: I missed that article. Care to share the link?